# How I should add my own styles to the sub-theme of boostrap theme in drupal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Boostrasp Drupal Theme](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and it's working without CDN, but now I have a question, where should I add my own styles? 
Do I need to create a new css file and add this in the `.info` file? 
I ask that the following part is not clear to me

> IF USING THE LESS MODULE Change the stylesheets include of your
>   sub-theme's .info file from css/style.css to less/style.less. These
>   will be generated once the theme is enabled and viewed. If this
>   doesn't work, make sure you are using 7.x-3.0-rc1 or higher.

If i am using `less/style.less` where can I put my own styles?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Subtheme and set your settings there. Do followings:

1. Copy bootstrap_subtheme folder into your /sites/all/themes folder
2. Disable your original bootstrap theme and enable your subtheme in your drupal 'Appearance'
3. Edit your /sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/css/style.css file to your needs or include any .css files into that file.